# How does S&P schedule reviews of sovereign credit ratings?

Tags: united-kingdom, international, government-bonds, credit-rating-agency

It's not too hard to find current sovereign credit ratings, but I need more info.  I believe that the major ratings agencies schedule reviews of different countries (or banks, etc.) so what I'd like to know is this:

**Where I can find the schedule for Standard & Poor's sovereign credit ratings reviews (especially the U.K.)? How rigorously do they stick to their schedule?**

I'm sure they wouldn't promise not to revise more quickly if there is a financial crisis, but I'm interested in the general pattern, to the extent one exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

S&P doesn't use a fixed schedule. I emailed Standard and Poor's Rating Desk to ask, however, and they confirmed that:

> There is no set schedule for the updating of our Sovereign Credit Ratings. Furthermore, these ratings are reviewed at least once every 1-2 years, and the reports are updated whenever a review is completed.

They also sent me a PDF with information on how they rate sovereign debt. I believe the actual PDF is only available to users that register (their website says registration is free), but you can find a [cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3alp_c2GlkylsJ%3awww.standardandpoors.com/ratings/articles/en/us/%3FarticleType%3DHTML%26assetID%3D1245330236378+%22Standard+%26+Poor%27s+rating+process+is+typically+initiated+when+the+issuer+or+its+representative+requests+a+rating+for+a+particular+debt+issue.%22&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) on Google.

In the section titled **"Process For Rating Government Issuers"**, it says:

> For government issuers, Standard & Poor's rating process is typically initiated when the issuer or its representative requests a rating for a particular debt issue. **...**
>
> Most sovereign issuers have rating agreements with us, but some sovereign ratings are classified as "unsolicited" because we do not have a rating agreement with the issuer. **We continue to rate these sovereigns when we believe there is significant market interest in them** and there is also sufficient public information of reliable quality to support our analysis and ongoing surveillance.

The portion I emphasize probably explains why ratings were published more frequent during the height of various debt crises; not only is the market more interested in credit ratings during such periods, but new information relevant to market conditions was continually coming to light in some cases.

On their [rating list](http://www.standardandpoors.com/ratings/sovereigns/ratings-list/en/us?sectorName=null&subSectorCode=39&filter=U), S&P states that their ratings for the UK are unsolicited. I asked for clarification on this and they responded that although there aren't any set dates for such reviews, they usually take place "once or twice a year." Ratings are published once the review is completed, which according to the document linked above, "typically takes four to six weeks to complete, but can run longer or shorter."

**Short answer:** You can probably expect new ratings to be published about twice a year for the UK because it's a sizable economy and major issuer of sovereign debt, but apart from that, S&P doesn't follow a set schedule.

Comment: What a great answer!

Comment: Thanks, this is great.  I'll mark it correct in a few days... I think it will get more attention from others if I don't mark it correct yet.

Comment: @MichaelBishop I should mention that since S&P last completed a review of the UK's debt in [April](http://www.guardian.co.uk/business/2013/apr/05/uk-triple-a-credit-rating-standard-and-poors), it may be several months before they complete another. I didn't add this into the answer because the information is localized to just now, but I wanted to add it just so you have a general time frame for the next one. Maybe sometime in September - November?